# Linux kernel: zap_page_range() duration

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

`zap_page_range` is defined in `mm/memory.c`. Here is how it is [defined](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=2.4.37#L360):

```
 /*
  * remove user pages in a given range.
  */
 void zap_page_range(struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long address, unsigned long size)
 {
         mmu_gather_t *tlb;
         pgd_t * dir;
         unsigned long start = address, end = address + size;
         int freed = 0;

         dir = pgd_offset(mm, address);

         /*
          * This is a long-lived spinlock. That's fine.
          * There's no contention, because the page table
          * lock only protects against kswapd anyway, and
          * even if kswapd happened to be looking at this
          * process we _want_ it to get stuck.
          */
         if (address >= end)
                 BUG();
         spin_lock(&mm->page_table_lock);
         flush_cache_range(mm, address, end);
         tlb = tlb_gather_mmu(mm);

         do {
                 freed += zap_pmd_range(tlb, dir, address, end - address);
                 address = (address + PGDIR_SIZE) & PGDIR_MASK;
                 dir++;
         } while (address && (address < end));

         /* this will flush any remaining tlb entries */
         tlb_finish_mmu(tlb, start, end);

         /*
          * Update rss for the mm_struct (not necessarily current->mm)
          * Notice that rss is an unsigned long.
          */
         if (mm->rss > freed)
                 mm->rss -= freed;
         else
                 mm->rss = 0;
         spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);
}
```

For some reason, I want this function to be executed as long as possible. Can anyone tell me how to do this? If the `size` is really big, will it take longer?

Comment: What abput putting a very long for cycle inside ?

Comment: @Claudio I'm sorry but I don't catch. I can not change code anything inside `zap_page_range`. I can only change the parameters `*mm`, `address`, `size`.

Comment: @Claudio Let's say, is the time taken by `zap_page_range` associated with the parameters?

Comment: `For some reason` - you want to explode some security deficiency in this function(or in the function which calls this one), so you need to elaborate some user-space parameters, which can cause this function to operate much longer that usual. Am I right? It is just for clarity, there is no problems with such questions here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes. That's just what I'm doing. I would to stay on this function longer to leave time for other threads to do something.

Comment: Do-while cycle internally iterates over all pages in the region. For every page it checks, whether it is swapped, and, if it is, frees also corresponded swap (see [that line](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=2.4.37#L323)). Operations with swap seems to be relatively long, so you can try to pass address range, which contains currently swapped pages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Many thanks for the hint. I'm sorry to bother you but how I know wether an address range contains swapped pages from my user code? How do I do it?

Comment: I don't know. Try to investigate by yourself.